# In org .commons.ziparchiveentry how to give the filename in foreign languages

Tags: java, zip, php-ziparchive

In ZipArchiveEntry how to define the filename(files that are zipped have name in the foreign language other than english). When i define

ZipArchiveEntry ze = new ZipArchiveEntry(filename);

It works fine for linux machines but not for windows. please help.

**update**

Using ZipArchiveEntry i trying to zip the indivdual files with name in foreign language. After zipped i extract the file from that zip. In linux it returns the filename correctly. But in windows filenames are corrupted

The same issue reported while using jdk also.

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4244499

http://www.coderanch.com/t/454532/java/java/Corrupt-file-compression

Answer (score 0):

You could get the filename implicitly by using the getEntries method

```
Enumeration<?> en = zip.getEntries();
ZipArchiveEntry zipEntry = null;
while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
    zipEntry = (ZipArchiveEntry) en.nextElement();
}
```

You can then call getName on zipEntry, to check the name

```
"i18n name string".equals(zipEntry.getName())
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm trying to zip file with foreign name. please tel me how to provide the encoding for the filename in zipArchiveentry

Comment: I might missing the point. Do you want to extract all files in the zip? Is your problem the presentation in the windows file manager?

Comment: I think that the problem may not be the ZipArchiveEntry but the Regional Settings of windows. Go to settings->Regional and Language Options->Advanced and set the non unicode language in which the filenames are written.